# Is there a way to perform this subsampling algorithm in numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, bigdata

The algorithm just builds up a new list from an input data array.  It only appends a new element from the input array once the element has crossed the visibleDelta threshold of the previous stored element:

```
def subsample(data, visibleDelta):
    subsampled = [data[0]]

    for point in data[1:]:
        if abs(point - subsampled[len(subsampled) - 1]) > visibleDelta:
            subsampled.append(point)

    return subsampled
```

Problem is I need this to run on very large datasets (~1B values), and I'd like to use numpy or some other numerical library to do this if possible.

I should probably mention that the 'real' function won't just deal with a 1D array of data.  The input data will be a pandas dataframe, with the first column being x values, and the second being y values (I'll be comparing the y values).

Any way to do this efficiently?

Answer (score 2):

if you want to track the data in this way, numpy is not the good tool, See Numba or Cython for efficiency.

A slightly different approach is to determine threshold and look when data reach them :

```
data=sin(arange(1e6)/3e4)
visibledelta=0.2
cat=floor(data/visibledelta)
subsample=arange(data.size-1)[diff(cat).astype(bool)]
plot(data)
plot(subsample,data[subsample],'o')
```

which give :

[image]

Some adjust may be done, but the data is splitted in chunks.